# Using referenced rows create merged column headers in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I would like to achieve the below, where column `A` is referenced by row 1 for merged column headers:

[image: Referenced Column Row to Merged Header Columns]

I can use `=INDEX(Sheet!$A$2:$A$99,COLUMN(A1),1)` and paste this into each merged column changing the COLUMN value from `A` to `B` to `C` but if I drag it across it doesn't work. I've tried setting 2 or 3 of them correctly and selecting all of them to drag across as well but it doesn't work either.

I am using the current version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN()+1,3)=0,INDEX($A$2:$A$6,(COLUMNS($B1:B$1)+2)/3,1),"")
```